# Writing to stdin of background process

Tags: linux, bash, background-process, stdin

I'm on an Ubuntu 10.04 box, and started a server in the background (myserver &) over ssh. It's been running fine, but I need a way to get at the server's stdin, as the only way to control the server is through this method.

Is there some way to get at the stdin of an already-running process so I can write to it (and hopefully read its stdout)? Obviously, if I were going to be doing this now, I'd start it with a FIFO redirecting to stdin, but unfortunately it's a little late for that now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you just bring it back to the foreground? ('jobs' will list your current background process, 'fg $X' will bring the job back to the foreground, ctrl+b will pause the job and return you to your shell, while 'bg' will continue the paused process in the background)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try writing to it's /proc pid directory. Say your daemons' pid is 2000, try writing to /proc/2000/fd/0

Comment: Thanks... I found that right after I posted this (after a day of looking--typical).

That seems to work (as far as actually sending data to the program). Unfortunately, the program doesn't accept the commands.

I tested it running the server on my local computer, and sure enough, I see the data appear, but the program doesn't recognize the commands. I have to manually press enter on the server terminal, and then it just says unrecognized command. Maybe some java weirdness? I'm stuck...

Comment: how about echo -e "something\n" > /proc/2000/fd/0?

Comment: Actually, this is not alway sworking as /proc/<pid>/fd/0 points to /dev/pts<some number> on at least some systems...

Comment: The first answer to http://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi/178470 notes that this approach doesn't actually work.

Comment: This does not actually work. Your shell normally (when no pipes or redirections are used) starts a command with file descriptors `0` through `2` set to the same file, which normally is a virtual terminal (something like `/dev/pty/...`). The command then _reads_ from FD `0` and _writes_ to FD `1` and `2` to communicate with the virtual terminal (e.g. over SSH or directly with your terminal emulator). If any other process accesses that file (e.g. through `/proc`), exactly the same thing happens, i.e. _writing_ to it writes to the terminal and not to the command.

Answer (score 34):

You could start you server with a named pipe (fifo) as its input:

```
mkfifo /tmp/srv-input
cat > /tmp/srv-input &
echo $! > /tmp/srv-input-cat-pid
cat /tmp/srv-input | myserver &
```

The `cat > /tmp/srv-input &` is important to avoid your server to receive a EOF.  At least one process must have the fifo opened in writing so your server does not receive a EOF.  The PID of this command is saved in the `/tmp/srv-input-cat-pid` file for latter kill.

In your case where you've already started your server, you have to use a debugger such as `gdb` to attach to your process to redirect its `stdin` to the fifo:

```
gdb -p PID
call close(0)
call open(0, "/tmp/srv-input", 0600)
```

And then do something like bellow to send input to your server (in another terminal window if necessary):

```
echo "command" > /tmp/srv-input
```

To send a EOF to your server, you need to kill the `cat > /tmp/srv-input` process which PID has been saved in the `/tmp/srv-input-cat-pid file`.

In the case of GDB, just quit GDB and EOF will be sent.

Comment: this is a much more portable approach than the one from @katriel as  /proc/2000/fd/0 is not stdin on all systems.

Comment: The trick with the "cat > /tmp/srv-input &" saved me some headaches. Thank you!

Comment: What about 
`mkfifo /tmp/srv-input;
tail -f /tmp/srv-input | myserver &` ? This'll keep the pipe open as well...

Comment: @bk138: it looks to me as tail should work, but there is only one way to know for sure: test.

Comment: `tail` doesn't work, but appended this to finish the job: `cat /tmp/srv-input | myserver; kill -9 `cat /tmp/srv-input-cat-pid` && rm /tmp/srv-input-cat*`

Comment: I know the edit that added it is a community one, but what version of `open` is this using that allows passing `0` (presumably the STDIN fd?) as the first argument? Both `gdb` and `gcc` return `-1` when I make that `call` (though I suppose that could be for any number of reasons).

Answer (score 7):

Same as above, but 'cat' did not work for me.
The file got EOF and ended after sending one command.

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo /tmp/srv-input
tail -f /tmp/srv-input | myserver &
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more elegant solution that solves the issues with  `tail -f` and `cat`

- Create a named pipe to route STDIN through: `mkfifo /data/in`.
- Block it for writing, so it does not get closed when your process read all of the current contents: `sleep infinity > /data/in &`.

Sleeping forever is better than `tailf -f /dev/null` because tailf uses inotify resources and will be triggered each time some app sends data to /dev/null. You can see this by running `strace` on it. It is also better than `cat > /dev/null &` because `cat` will be itself disconnected from STDIN, which in turn will close `/data/in`.

- Start your process in the background with the `/data/in` providing STDIN: `application < /data/in &`.

This works better than using piping from tail `tail -f /data/in | application &` because the pipe will only get terminated if the tail stops, but if your application crashes the pipe will keep running.

- Halt waiting for the application to finish. `wait $(pidof application)`.

This uses no resources and if the application crashes your script after the `wait` will be executed. You can add an application restart loop around it if you wish.

- To terminate the application gracefully trap and relay the system signals to it with `trap 'kill -SIGTERM $(pidof app)' SIGTERM`