# Write to the stdin of a running process with the same effect/behaviour of directly writing

Tags: linux, stdin

This [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi) answers only partial my question. My problem is that writing to the stdin of the running process using the FD of process on the /proc filesystem does not have the same effect.

Problem:

1. start nc to listen on port 10000 (this process is called further nc 1)

   ```
   nc -l 10000
   ```
2. start another nc to send chars to the listening nc (this will be nc 2)

   ```
   nc localhost 10000
   ```
3. Write to the stdin on the nc 2

   ```
   echo "some chars here" >> /proc/[PID-nc-2]/fd/0
   ```

the problem: "some chars here" do not get to the listening nc (nc 1), BUT are shown on the console of the nc 2.

Question: 
why and is it possible to make this working?

Answer (score 11):

This doesn't work as you expect because `/proc/<PID>/fd/0` isn't a pipe. If you invoke the sending side with it's stdin connected to a pipe it will work

On the receiving host

```
nc -l 10000
```

On the sending host

```
mkfifo my.fifo
cat >my.fifo &
cat my.fifo | nc remotehost.tld 10000
```

Now you can

```
echo "Hello World" >my.fifo
myprog >my.fifo
```

Note that the `cat >my.fifo` is required to keep the fifo open otherwise an EOF gets sent and the connection gets closed prematurely. To close the connection down you need to kill the cat process that is holding the fifo open.

Comment: Very helpful! In my case this actually made it *easier* to communicate with a process because the fifo perms can allow a normal user to affect a sudo'ne script.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the answer to the post you linked, you need to write to `/proc/pid/fd/0`, not `/proc/pid/fd/1`.

Comment: I corrected my question. But anyway: I tried both /fd/0 and /fd/1. The question remains...

Comment: i have tried this, but facing little issue. it does posts the required domain to telnet, but i think it requires some sort of carriage return or new line character, which i am unable to pass to it