# Write to the stdin of a running process (without changing the way of starting the program)

Tags: linux, stdin

In this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/407902/write-to-the-stdin-of-a-running-process-with-the-same-effect-behaviour-of-direct) there is described how to start a program and then to send data to the stdin of the program (with FIFOs). But what to do if the program is already running, and I cannot re/start the program?

Comment: Operating System? Type of program?

Answer (score -1):

I once wrote a program to do the reverse (monitor output of an already started program). It's not a simple operation; it relies on using ptrace() to attach to the process and intercept system calls. When you detect a read() system call, inject the data.