# Write to stdin of a running process using pipe

Tags: linux, process, stdin

I am in a similar situation as in this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/407902/write-to-the-stdin-of-a-running-process-with-the-same-effect-behaviour-of-direct?rq=1) 
But I couln't get the solution provided there to work in my situation as the answer seems related to that question only.

In particular, I couldnt understand what was the purpose of

```
cat my.fifo | nc remotehost.tld 10000
```

In my case, I have a process running and waiting for input. how can I send input to that process using named pipes?

I've tried `echo 'h' > /proc/PID/fd/0` it just displays 'h' on the process' window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just ignore the lines containing `nc`, the OP in this questions wants to use it to transfer data over the network via `nc`.

That leaves you with:

```
mkfifo yourfifo
cat > yourfifo &
mypid=$!
yourprogram < yourfifo
```

Now you can sent data to your program with

```
echo "Hello World" > yourfifo
```

If you are done, terminate your program, issue the command `kill $mypid` to get rid of the dummy process to keep the FIFO open and `rm yourfifo` to get rid of the named pipe.

Comment: what is `cat > yourfifo &` doing?