# Pass arguments to a persistent telnet sessions

Tags: linux, whois

I have a whois service, which allows me to telnet to it and keep the telnet connection open without any time limit on it. I have to do thousands of whois through that telnet session. For example, to whois a domain, i do

```
echo "mydomain.com"; sleep 5| telnet whoismyserver.com 3454
```

I cannot run this command for thousands of whois. So is there any way that i can keep the telnet sessions open and pass arguments to it?

i want to keep a persistent telnet connection. and pass arguments to it. is that possible? for example, in above command, i can only pass argument of "echo domain" Once, but i want to pass long list of Echos, but with different intervals, and that too to only open persistent telnet sessions. i want to pass all commands one by one, at different time to one telnet session

Comment: o.O What are you trying to do exactly, and why?

Comment: Simply, i want to keep a persistent telnet connection. and pass arguments to it. is that possible? for example, in above command, i can only pass argument of "echo domain" Once, but i want to pass long list of Echos, but with different intervals, and that too to only open persistent telnet sessions. i want to pass all commands one by one, at different time to one telnet session

Comment: Sure.  You write a program that opens up the network connection to the remote server and then reads input from stdin and sends it to the remote server.  You could probably accomplish this with `expect`, although you'd probably be better off with Python or Perl or Ruby or something.

Comment: can you provide any example of it? any implementation ?which i can see to get an idea?

Comment: Try using a named pipe http://serverfault.com/a/407923/9517

Comment: Search CPAN archive for Perl module NET::Telnet and check the examples.

Comment: @Iain - post that as another answer, that's a good one that I wasn't really familiar with.

Comment: @mfinni: tested and done.

Answer (score 5):

Why can't you just run whois on your local machine and script/batch that? Or just telnet to the other system and script it there? Having to do this routed via telnet to another system seems awful.

Having said that, it *is* what Expect is made for (points for @larsks) , so if you have to do this, use that.

/edit - We're not your Google, but here's a start : http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Happy to hear the reason for the downvote. I offered 3 solutions - local scripting in two places and using Expect to do what he's asking.

Comment: i have custom application and it has this Special requirement.. its not a simple whois.

Comment: So, as @larsks said and I repeated, use Expect. It's what it does. It opens a telnet connection that you can programatically interact with.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do this with a named pipe (fifo)

```
mkfifo my.pipe
cat >my.pipe &
cat my.fifo | telnet telnet whois.iana.org  43
echo "serverfault.com" >>my.fifo
```

This seems to work in as much as the echo command sends serverfault.com to the whois server. I don't have access to a server which allows persistent connections so I can't test it for more than one name. but it should be a smop to read your domain names and echo them to the pipe.

If you want to collect the output in a file then just redirect stdout

```
cat my.fifo | telnet telnet whois.iana.org  43 >some.output.file
```

Comment: its fine, but i am not able to automate this process through bash profile. as the time limit for which telnet remains open, is 30 min, on server. so i very hard to track and keep telnet alive :(

Answer (score 1):

Search CPAN archive for Perl module **NET::Telnet** and check the examples.

```
use Net::Telnet ();
$t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 10,
                      Prompt => '/bash\$ $/');
$t->open($host);
$t->login($username, $passwd);
@lines = $t->cmd("who");
print @lines;
```

Comment: how to use specific port?

Comment: Check the module on CPAN - http://goo.gl/6HLtNm. The constructor has many parameters, one of them is a TCP port.